# Routing with Angular doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application rails with angular, i create directory `/app/assets/javascripts/angular/templates` to create my views.

My *route.js.coffe*

```
app.config ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider
  .when('/task', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/task/index.html'
    controller: 'TaskCtrl'
  })
```

My index.slim

```
.container
  h2
    |What would you like to do?

  a href="#/watchlist"
    | Watchlist
  | &nbsp or &nbsp
  a href="#/task"
    | Task

  div class="row" ng-view=""
```

When i click the link "Task" nothing happens. I see the following message on the console:

> Started GET "/templates/task/index.html" for 192.168.1.106 at 2014-08-29 08:49:17 -0300
>     ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/templates/task/index.html"):

My index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="TaskCtrl">
  <h2>teste</h2>
</div>
```

and my route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'home/index'

  scope :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    resources :tasks
    resources :stocks
  end

  root 'home#index'

end
```

Comment: How are you binding the app to your application?

Answer (score 1):

use "#task" and "#watchlist", your when is for html5mode, set using the $locationProvider.

Comment: i tried html5mode before, when it was false and true, i just can't remember using '#/' in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are binding the application itself to the view.

You can bootstrap it to the document

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['appname']);
```

Or bind it someone on your index

```
<body ng-app="appName">

</body>
```